# Responsive fullscreen bg on first page (bootstrap 3)

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, web

I was trying to achieve this using Webplate, but I decided that I need to force myself to learn bootstrap. I'm using a clean, empty dist and I want to emulate the effect that webplate framework offers by default

Responsive background image for the intro of a single page website.

The best example I found online is this http://creativedistrict.com/

I'm looking all over stack for examples but can't find any. If I can get some help, at least direction, I would appreciate it. I'm a novice, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of the Bootstrap framework as a bunch of CSS and optionally JS, then in theory it's not too difficult to combine with something like Webplate.

To add the CSS and JS files, you could download Bootstrap, grab the files you need, add them to your Webplate project files, and then link to them in the head of your Webplate document.

Alternatively, http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ has details on where to get CDN versions of these files so that may be simpler for you.

Once you have the Bootstrap CSS and JS linked into your Webplate page, you are good to go. If you check out the Bootstrap website you'll find plenty of code you can copy and paste.

When combining different frameworks like this, you need to use some caution because of CSS or potentially more serious JS conflicts. I did some quick tests using the Webplate download from http://getwebplate.com/#download and using the Bootstrap CDN links of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
and  

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The CSS seemed to be fairly compatible, the JS might take a bit more work.

Good luck!